# How to ignore the error from mv: cannot move ‘XXXXXX to a sub directory of itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel, mv

On our RHEL 7.6 server we create the following folder

```
# mkdir -p /var/data/data-logs_temp
```

the second part is to move all content under  `/var/data/` to `/var/data/data-logs_temp` by:

```
# mv /var/data/* /var/data/data-logs_temp
```

but the output that we get from the `mv` command is:

```
mv: cannot move ‘/var/data/data-logs_temp’ to a sub directory of itself, ‘/var/data/data-logs_temp/data-logs_temp’
```

**The `mv` command is correct about this**.

But; is it possible to tell `mv` to ignore this as we need the exit code from the `mv` command to be `0`?

Or maybe any other option that ignore the move the sub directory of itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash's "extended glob" syntax to exclude the data-logs_temp subdirectory from the list of files to be moved:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv /var/data/!(data-logs_temp) /var/data/data-logs_temp
```

See [Greg's wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu) for more info about extended globs.

Comment: please note that we need to move all data under /var/data/* to target so I not understand why mv /var/data/!(data-logs_temp)?  ( so why you not set the *    , in mv /var/data/!(data-logs_temp) ? )

Comment: @yael  Because then data-logs_temp would then contain itself, and its parent directory would be itself, and the directory tree would have a loop in itself, so it would not be a tree anymore.

Comment: @yael `/var/data/*` expands to everything in /var/data (including data-logs_temp); but you can't move a directory into itself which causes the error. `/var/data/!(data-logs_temp)` expands to everything in  /var/data *except* for data-logs_temp, which is (I presume) what you actually want to move.

Comment: @yael `!(foo)` is saying *Expand everything **but** what's in this parentheses*. `*` expand *everything* except dot files (normally). Try this in a directory `touch a b c d e` then `printf 'TEST1: "%s"\n' *` - then `printf 'TEST2: "%s"\n' !(c)` (after extglob ofc.)

Comment: its not work on my bash script , we get   "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: we have bash version - GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: @yael Did you enable extended glob syntax (with `shopt -s extglob`) first?

Comment: yes I set this in the beginning of the bash script

Comment: @yael Then you need to post the script.

Answer (score 0):

In a simpler Unix/Linux world, without invoking extended options, one would:

(a) `mkdir data-logs_temp` in any directory you had which was in the same filesystem as `/var/data`, and writeable by you, and not in any subtree of `/var/data` (`/var` would be acceptable if you had write permissions).

(b) `cd /var/data` and `mv * /wherever/data-logs_temp`, avoiding expanding all the globbed names with their full directory. This does not copy the data, only create links; and it does not try to copy  directory into itself.

(c) `mv /wherever/data-logs_temp /var/data`. This only moves one link, and preserves the tree structure.